# Do not refresh view in Angular after certain event

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to use certain library (XYZ) in my Angular application. When I initialise certain object in the library, it attaches and (as far as I understand) starts emitting some pointerover events. This triggers refresh of all rendered components.

When I destroy the object from the XYZ library, it keeps emitting the events when I just move around with the mouse. This drastically reduces the performance. So at every pointerover event (1000s events when I change move around with a mouse) it triggers something like:

```
 executeTemplate (core.js:7457)
    at refreshView (core.js:7326)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7132)
    at refreshView (core.js:7376)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8427)
    at refreshView (core.js:7350)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8473)
```

I understand this happens on any Click event by default which (I assume) is fine. But there are simply way too many events triggered through the pointerover events.

1. Can I somehow tell Angular not to refresh on pointerover event?
2. Or, would you be solving the problem differently (apart from talking to the library maintainer)

Comment: Is XYZ the name of the library?

Comment: That was just a made up reference. The is ContentBuilder.Js though I believe it is not really relevant.

Comment: It might be interesting to see how you initialise said library in your code

Comment: It is rather simple like  this.contentBuilder = new ContentBuilder({
      container: '.builder-div'})